# How can I get the window position/size from a different program's window?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, python-3.x, pyqt4

What I want to do is create a semi-transparent overlay over another program's window that displays stats on what is happening on the window in the background.  I know how to do everything that I want to do with this program except find the properties of window such as position, size, and title so I can position my transparent windows in front of the right window.  For example, if you don't know what I mean, if you play online poker and use Poker Tracker.  They have the transparent HUD that appears over each table.  I basically need to do the same type of thing.  I have searched many things and have not had any luck so far.  I will be using Qt4 or PyQt4 most likely for the GUI so if that toolkit provides the right functions to do this and I just haven't been able to find them yet, that would be great.  If I need to use another toolkit too, that doesn't matter.  If I need to use something other than the Qt tool kit I would still like to know.  However it can be done I would like to know.

Comment: Would probably help to know the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you have to use the Windows API.
GetWindowRect can do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But first you have to get the another Window hwnd, with something like FindWindow